# Need help building a regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on parsing some input messages and I have these two scenarios:

> product name one to pickup
>
> product name two to deliver
>
> product name three

As you can see the delivery details is optional (the system will take some assumptions if it is missing in the input). Also note that the product name can be in multiple words.

The input will be in the format:

```
[product name] to [verb]
```

but the `to [verb]` portion could be excluded because it's optional.

I wrote this regex to lookbehind for where 'to' is but because the first part of the regex accepts space between words it takes 'to pickup' or 'to deliver' in, so the last bit does not get anything.

```
(?<Item>(\w*\s*)+)\s*(?<DeliveryOption>((?<=to)\s*(PIC|DEL|PICKUP|DELIVERY|P|D|TAKEAWAY|AWAY))?)\s*$
```

How can I prioritize the last part to take the delivery option first?

Comment: What does the the "three" in `product name three` actually mean here then?

Comment: Could you provide some *examples*, please?

Comment: Is Regex a requirement? It would be much more readable using some `if` statements. IMO anyway

Comment: I feel like just doing `yourstring.Split(new string[] { " to " }, StringSplitOptions.None);` and checking out the second element of the result would be a LOT easier to debug.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just tried to come up with multi-word product item names. So the whole 'product name three' is for the group "Item" in the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting the text before parsing with regex sounds like the easiest option.

Answer (score 1):

Once I had a problem with parsing text when having words with spaces. What I did was replacing the spaces to underlines, performing my parsing operations, then reverting the underlines back to spaces.

In your case you could take the string before and after 'to' and do the replacement, and your words remain coherent. If regex already makes use of '_', you can use any other character, where you know it will never be used. Possibly even a set of multiple characters like "TRP7" if necessary. But maybe you don't need to use regex at all.

Comment: Good point. I am getting inclined to a similar idea raised in the comments of the question to actually split the string by 'to' and regex each part separately.